# the requested database cannot be opened

Tags: php, sql-server

When using the code `$db_conn = sqlsrv_connect($server,$connarray);` in PHP to connect to a database, I get the errors 42000 and 28000. $server is = (local).

As soon as I change the database in `$connarray` to a systemdatabase (e.g. MSreplication_options) the connection works with NO OTHER CHANGES to the code. And yes, the requested DB is on the server.

As I am not familiar with MS-SQL I have no idea where to set the missing rights. Or is there another error?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `databasename\Sicherheit\Schemas\dbo\Berechtigungen\Datenbankberechtigungen anzeigen\guest` and grant the appropriate rights. In the same place the assigned user as to be added too.

At least, thats the way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the user does not have sufficient rights to access the database. Change username to "root" because root has all privilege. hope this help